# Ubuntu 18.04 screen flickering issue

Tags: 18.04

I have an AMD RX560. Issue happened after Ubuntu fresh install when I decided to watch youtube videous. During youtube video watching my screen turns black for a few seconds.

I was installing AMD drivers but it did not help. I did not have such issue on windows 10.

Please advice what do I need to do to eliminate this issue.

Comment: Please post in English.

Comment: did you install the radeon driver ? I suggest you to install the rocm-dkms package from this repo: `deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/ xenial main`

Comment: installed the driver. I will try to do so thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "TearFree" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: to folders /etc/X11/ no file xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf what to do?

Comment: create the folder and the file and add these lines

Comment: thanks for the help, the problem is solved with the addition of the file

Comment: please press the up arrow (this answer is useful) on my answer